# Stop a button/function from triggering when pressing enter multiple times in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a login Button (dumb component) that triggers a function onClick:

```
<Button loading={this.state.isBusy}
        onClick={this.login}>Login</Button>
```

But the problem is that when the user types wrong credentials and hit the Enter key multiple times, the function is also triggered multiple times and a few warning messages show up all at once (warning message that says to the user that the credentials are wrong).

I have tried a few solution to fix this problem:

- Setting state is not a working solution as states aren't quickly enough modified.
- I have tried with ref, to disable the button, but I can't use the new version of it (*React.createRef()*) as its is only available for the version 16.3 of React and I am running with the version 16.2.
- I have tried to add disabled to the button with e.target: *onClick={(e) => this.login(e)}*, and then *e.target.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");* in the *login()* function, but this is not working when you hit enter quickly.
- And at last, I have tried to use a global variable in the class: this.isLoading = false; in order to use it instead of a state to stop the *login()* function to be triggered *if isLoading === true*.

So here I am, asking for help. Please tell me if I wasn't clear enough.

Thanks a lot in advance !

EDIT: Here is how I render the warnings in the login() function:

```
if(!this.state.usernameValue) {
  EventEmitter.emit(EventEmitter.events.messagePopup.OPEN_MESSAGE_POPUP_ALERT, {message: "Please enter a username or e-mail!"});
  return;
}

if(!this.state.passwordValue) {
  EventEmitter.emit(EventEmitter.events.messagePopup.OPEN_MESSAGE_POPUP_ALERT, {message: "Please enter a password!"});
  return;
}
```

Comment: How do you render the warning? Could you add the relevant code for it to your question?

Comment: A popular way of handling multiple form submits, is by showing a spinner while checking credentials. Please share a js fiddle for your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an alternative solution, which is to remove the focus of the inputs after Enter was hit:

```
login(elFocused) {
  if(elFocused) {
    elFocused = "." + elFocused;
    document.querySelector(elFocused).blur();
  }
}

<input onEnter={() => this.login("inputClassName")} />
```

This way I don't have to worry anymore for multiple Enter key hits as it is not possible anymore ;)
This is also working for the button!

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you were almost correct, and you can set ref with older react for 16.2

```
<button ref={btn => { this.btn = btn }} onClick={e => { this.handleClick(e) }}>

handleClick (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 this.btn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")

 login().then(() => {
   this.btn.removeAttribute("disabled")
 })
}
```

Comment: I actually tried it before, but it was throwing me an error in my console. And I prefer to avoid using ref anyway, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

handleClick=()=>{      the function block called after clicking submit

```
if(this.state.name===validation condition)
      //every time the validation fails
 {    this.setState({submit:false)   
      //submit must be in state with initial value =false
 }
 else {
   this.setState({submit:true})
 }
  if(this.state.submit===true){
      //Login API call or pass it to a function 
 }
}
<input type="text" onChange={(event)=> 
            {this.setState(name:event.target.value)}}
<button onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

`
every Time the validation check fails the if block is triggered and the API call won't be made.